# Unable to add image in question but I have enough reputation?

Tags: support, images

```
![enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVapl.png
```

This is the code I got when tried to add image in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299021/serializing-form-exotic-behaviour-in-ajax-response)

But image not being upload. Please help me where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Check it again, Image is successfully added.

Comment: That is simply the markdown for your image. It's not the live preview. Everything works as it should. If you weren't able to upload images, you wouldn't get that bit of "code".

Comment: @Lucifer If image is displaying? why in the question image is not diplaying ?

Comment: Ah, there was a bit problem, I edited it, Now you too can see it, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we have more than one image in the post it goes like below,

```
![Enter your description here][1]
![Enter your description here][2]
![Enter your description here][3]
```

.
.
.
 at the post end you have link of these as

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1.png 
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2.png 
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3.png
```

In your case, I saw following thing,

```
![Enter your description here][1] // missing 
![Enter your description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1.png  
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2.png
```

Note that both images has `[1]` this was the reason it was showing only one image to you. I have edit it properly and now it is showing both images.

Comment: I'm not able to see image in preview section or post posted also...

Comment: @Mr.Chowdary, see the updation please.

Comment: Sorry...I'm not able to see the image really...

Comment: seriously you are not able to see  image here ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299021/996493

Comment: please check this screenshot is it coming or not ?? [Click Here](http://www.sciweavers.org/download/new_bitmap_image_php03f9iJ.gif)

Comment: Are you able to see the screenshot without image displaying ?

Comment: [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jsSzW.png) how it shows to me, I am able to see both images.

Comment: I'm not able to see the images there too :( .. i will it outside. in office might be restricting.. but image displaying why it is stopping i don't know..?

Comment: let we confirm from other users, can anybody please confirm this ? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299021/996493) question displays two images after I update it. Please reply what you see.

Comment: I'm able to see the images in my mobile.. But still not in the system.. Might be some firewall stopping..

Comment: ok, good, so finally your problem is solved :)